# How to extract data from string

Tags: python, regex

My code is

```
import regex

word = '\x02|1280|SELECT|35;36|="214554"'.encode('ascii')

pattern = r'^(\x02)\|(\d{1,4})\|(SELECT|UPDATE|INSERT)\|(\d{1,2}+|;*)\|="(\w+)"'.encode('ascii')

print(regex.match(pattern, word).group(4))
```

and I'm interested in group 4 -> (\d{1,2}+|;*) that can have following pattern

- |one digit number|
- |two-digit number|
- |one/two-digit number; one/two-digit number; ... ; one/two-digit number|

I have tried different combination, but as I'm new to regex none of them returns data from group.

Comment: How about changing the pattern for group 4 to: `(\d{1,2}(?:;\d{1,2})*)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\d{1,2}+|;*` pattern matches 1 or 2 digits possessively or 0+ semi-colon. So, it is not what you need.

You need to write the pattern like this:

```
r'^(\x02)\|(\d{1,4})\|(SELECT|UPDATE|INSERT)\|(\d{1,2}(?:;\d{1,2})*)\|="(\w+)"'
```

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/CZQUDP99659).

The Group 4 pattern will look like `(\d{1,2}(?:;\d{1,2})*)`:

- `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `(?:` -  start of a non-capturing group that matches sequences of....

  - `;` - a semi-colon
  - `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `)*` - .... zero or more occurrences.

Comment: **NOTE**: For this regex to work, you may use a regular `re` Python module, no need for the more powerful PyPi regex module here.

Comment: Marked as correct answer because explanation is more detailed then @degant answer

Comment: @flebas: Note that since you have more than 15 rep points, you may also upvote those answers that proved helpful for you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow))

Answer (score 1):

How about changing the pattern for group 4 to: `(\d{1,2}(?:;\d{1,2})*)`?

- `\d{1,2}` represents one or two digits
- `(?:;\d{1,2})*` represents zero or more non-capturing groups that include a semi colon `;` followed by one or two digits numbers
- Important to mark the group as non-capturing by adding a `(?:` at the start

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5F70fX/1/)

Hope this helps!